# Issue with circular shift BITMASK

Tags: iphone, ios, enums, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

i'm having one enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Node) {    
    NodeTop     ,      
    NodeLeft    ,
    NodeBottom  ,
    NodeRight   ,
} ;
```

and property as,

```
@property Node node;
```

now in my controller i'm assigning node multiple values using pipeline,

```
node =top | left | bottom | right ;
```

(Q-1 does node have 0000,0011 kind of values using NodeTop,Left OR simply final result of ORing of top|left|bottom|right?)

this way `NSLog("%d",node);` giving result 1.

now if node contains 0001 , i want to left shift it by 1 so i tried

```
node<<1;
```

which changes node value 1 to 2 but is it does not seem really changing 0001 to 0010?

in short i want node to have value like 0001,

and later on i want to shift its value like,

0010

0100

1000

0001

0010
...

Any help? let me know if question is not clear!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NS_OPTIONS` to create a bit mask where each value is defined as `1<<n`. [This NSHipster post](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) explain the usage of both `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTIONS`.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, Node) {    
    NodeTop    = 1 << 0, // 1   
    NodeLeft   = 1 << 1, // 2
    NodeBottom = 1 << 2, // 4
    NodeRight  = 1 << 3  // 8
};
```

That way when you write

```
NodeTop | NodeBottom
```

it will be the same as

```
...0001 | ...0100 = ....0101
```

And shifting the bit will move it to the next option

```
Node node = NodeBottom<<1; // = NodeRight
```

since `...0100 << ...1000`.

Comment: thanks, it helped me. any idea how can i rotate right these binary as, 0001 1000 0100 0010 0001?

Comment: Your bit shifts are backwards on the enum.

Comment: @borrrden Ops, that's a bad typo. Thanks for finding it

Comment: Now you made them all backwards :-O.  You switched the wrong ones.  I meant switch the ones inside the enum definition (1 << 0, 1 << 1, etc).  1 >> 1 is 0, 1 >> 2 is 0, and 1 >> 3 is 0.

Comment: @borrrden It's morning and I haven't had coffee yet :( Should be fixed now

Answer (score 3):

> which changes node value 1 to 2 but is it does not seem really changing 0001 to 0010?

It does. `0010` binary is `2` decimal.

Comment: if i have,

node = 0 | 1 | 0 | 1;

so it will contain 1, right?

now i need to shift node so that it contains 1 0 1 0, 

is it by node<<1 ?

after node<<1, it gives 2 rather 10 in decimal

Comment: @BaSha And that's fine. `1 << 1` is 2. Shifting ain't no decimal.

Comment: but i have work with binary not a decimal which comes after ORING operation

Comment: @BaSha There's no such thing a "binary" or "decimal". There are integers, which are multiplied by two when shifted to the left one place. And then decimal `1` becomes `2`, and binary `1` becomes binary `10`. I suggest you get an idea about number systems and the representation of integers in C before proceeding any further.

Comment: thanks, decimal in sense if i assign 1|0|1|0 or 0|1|0|1 to node, it will contain 1, and after shifting it will give 2 in both case. but i have work with 0|1|0|1 or 1|0|1|0 and not a resulting 2, anyways i'm going more deep in number systems.

Comment: @BaSha Don't worry about the number system in which you are viewing the number. You print it as decimal, you get `2`. You print it as binary, you get `10`. It's all the same number in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can only bitwise OR these values together in a meaningful way if you make each value correspond to a different bit, e.g.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Node) {    
    NodeTop = 1,      
    NodeLeft = 2,
    NodeBottom = 4,
    NodeRight = 8
};

node = NodeTop;    // 0b0001 = 0x01 = 1
node <<= 1;        // 0b0010 = 0x02 = 2 = NodeLeft
node <<= 1;        // 0b0100 = 0x04 = 4 = NodeBottom
```

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist NS_OPTIONS does not do that for you.  In fact I'm not really sure *what* it does except make things more understandable for the person reading the code.

Comment: @borrrden That was my understanding after reading about it but you are right. They seem to be defined the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Well as for the circular bit shifting, I think the best you can do is something like this (quickly thrown together C code)

```
enum test { 
    test1 = 1,
    test2 = 2,
    test4 = 4,
    test8 = 8
};

static enum test val(enum test input) {
    while(input >= 16) //Or whatever max bit you want
        input = input >> 4; //Be sure to shift by the appropriate number

    return input;
}
```

Then when you run this code:

```
enum test foo = test1;
foo = val(foo << 5);
```

`foo` will be `test2`